# jQuery sending only the first character of string with each() and this

Tags: jquery, froogaloop

I'm trying to call Froogaloop for various iframes on a single page, but `this` is returning only the first character of the playerID ('vimeo1', 'vimeo2', etc.)

I log playerId (a string) immediately before each() and it returns fine, but as soon as I get inside each(), `this` becomes "v".

```
jQuery(playerId).each(function(){
  Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing in `playerID` one at a time? In other words, is your `playerID` an array of strings or a single string?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If `playerId` is a string, as you say, `$()` will interpret it as a *selector*. If it is not a valid selector (and chances are it isn't), then nothing will be matched and `each()` won't have anything to iterate over.

Comment: To clarify, I grab the ID by pulling all the elements of a certain class and then getting their IDs:

    jQuery('.player').each(function(){
  var id = this.id;
  playersList.push(id);

 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referencing an element on the page with playerID? Is "vimeo1" a class name or ID? If so, the string needs to be either `.vimeo1` or `#vimeo1`. That way, jQuery will search for an element like `jQuery('.vimeo1')` instead of `jQuery('vimeo1')`

```
var playerId = '.vimeo1';

jQuery(playerId).each(function(){
  Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
});
```

Comment: My god. Talk about basic. I was using some other conditional above that to add "#" when needed, which didn't work so I assumed it wasn't the issue. Turns out that conditional is messed up. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what kind of parameter froogaloop expects, but if it is a string from the playerID array this should do what you want:

```
$.each(playerId, function(index, value){
    Froogaloop(value).addEvent('ready', ready);
})
```